# Is it acceptable to solicit edit suggestions on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

If I post a question that I need help finding a better title for, or if I need some edit assistance for clarity, is it appropriate to ask for edit help on meta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, I'd say if your question doesn't seem to be getting any attention, or the answers you are getting are off-track, coming to meta to ask how to make your question more clear would be okay.

If you end up with a companion question on meta for every question you ask on the main site, that might not be received very well.